# monero-wallet-cli failing to create wallet on docker

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I'm running a full node. It's completely synced with the network and running fine. I'm running it on docker using the the following command;

```
# Monero Daemon
  monero:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.monero
    user: "${UID:-1000}:${GID:-1000}"
    volumes:
      - ./infrastructure/monero/blockchain:/home/monero/.bitmonero
  # Monero Wallet
  wallet:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.monero
    user: "${UID:-1000}:${GID:-1000}"
    links: ["monero"]
    volumes:
      - ./infrastructure/monero/wallet:/home/monero/.bitmonero
    command: >
      monero-wallet-cli
      --generate-new-wallet TestWallet
      --use-english-language-names
      --daemon-address monero:18081
      --trusted-daemon
```

When trying to start `monero-wallet-cli`. It fails saying `If your display freezes, exit blind with ^C, then run again with --use-english-language-names`. I also tried adding `--mnemonic-language english` and it still failed.

When checking the logs. It looks like this;
`2023-06-09 00:37:15.300        7f6d26ac7400    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO`

- Was there something else I needed to pass?
- Is the monero-wallet-cli not reaching the daemon?

Comment: The log you posted is just an INFO message stating the logging categories. Perhaps you should share your docker files rather than simply the compose source and perhaps show the *error* message of where it's failing.